# Como utilizar a abordagem de upload salvando o caminho no banco?

Tags: java-ee, jsf-2.2, upload

Criei um projeto Web Java que está utilizando JSF com PrimeFaces, Maven, CDI com JPA. Minha aplicação web está conseguindo inserir os registros com sucesso, a aplicação se trata de um cadastro de noticias, aonde é necessário também inserir uma foto, a abordagem de *upload* utilizado é salvar o caminho da imagem no banco.

Consegui concluir metade da implementação do *upload*, ou seja, tive sucesso em salvar a imagem na pasta, no entanto não consegui salvar o caminho da pasta no banco.

Está tudo funcionando, por causa disso somente irei colocar pedaços do código para ter uma ideia. Pacote do *Repository*:

```
@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public Noticia guardar(Noticia noticia) {
    return manager.merge(noticia);
}
```

Pacote *Model* está todo mapeado corretamente com *get* e *set*:

```
private Long id;
private String titulo_noticia;
private Date data_noticia;
private String foto_noticia;
private String desc_noticia;
```

Pacote *Controller*:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroNoticiaBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Noticia noticia;
    private Part arquivo;
    private String nomeArquivoSaida;

    @Inject
    private CadastroNoticiaService cadastroNoticiaService;

    public CadastroNoticiaBean() {
        limpar();
    }

    public void limpar(){
        noticia = new Noticia();
    }

    public void salvar() {
        this.noticia = cadastroNoticiaService.salvar(this.noticia);
        upload();
        limpar();
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Noticia salva com sucesso! ");
    }

    public void upload() {

         nomeArquivoSaida = "C:/workspace Web/Projetos Profissionais/Fotos para teste/" + arquivo.getSubmittedFileName();   

         try (InputStream is = arquivo.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(nomeArquivoSaida)) {

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

//tentei colocar esse código abaixo para conseguir fazer o insert do caminh do
//banco, mas não tivesse resultado
            // preciso muito de ajuda para saber como resolver.
            noticia.setFoto_noticia(getNomeArquivoSaida());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Erro ao enviar arquivo.");
        }
    }

    public Noticia getNoticia() {
        return noticia;
    }

    public Part getArquivo() {
        return arquivo;    
    }

    public void setArquivo(Part arquivo) {
        this.arquivo = arquivo;
    }

    public String getNomeArquivoSaida() {

        return nomeArquivoSaida;
    }

    public void setNomeArquivoSaida(String nomeArquivoSaida) {
        this.nomeArquivoSaida = nomeArquivoSaida;
    }
}
```

Esse é o pedaço do código na pagina XHTML que envolve o problema:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Foto" />
<h:inputFile value="#{cadastroNoticiaBean.arquivo}"/>
```

Acredito que seja uma alteração simples, somente preciso saber qual é. Fiz um teste de *debug*:

[image]

[image]

[O projeto no GitHub](https://github.com/wladyband/VendeLancha/tree/master/VendeLancha).

Comment: Já tentou passar a String `nomeArquivoSaida` pro objeto?

Comment: como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Ao invés de passar o getNomeArquivoSaida, passa o nomeArquivoSaida e vê se funciona

Comment: Da algum erro quando voce tenta salvar no banco?

Comment: Não funcionou usando nomeArquivoSaida, e ele simplesmente não funciona e não gera mensagem de erro no console.

Comment: Quando você coloca um `System.out.println(nomeArquivoSaida)` ele exibe a mensagem com o caminho do arquivo?

Comment: O mais estranho é que ele exigi o caminho completo, quer que eu coloque o projeto no github para você dá uma olhada?

Comment: Pode colocar vou dar uma analisada.

Comment: Verifique o tamanho do campo no banco de dados também.

Comment: existe um aquivo na raiz que tem que clicar com start application para criar a tabela noticia.

Comment: Entendi, me passa o projeto

Comment: esse é o caminho  >>>>    https://github.com/wladyband/VendeLancha/tree/master/VendeLancha

Comment: eu coloquei tb na postagem

Comment: Já está visualizando?

Comment: Vou ver agora, estava almoçando

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no seu método salvar:

```
 public void salvar() {
        this.noticia = cadastroNoticiaService.salvar(this.noticia);
        upload();
        limpar();
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Noticia salva com sucesso! ");
    }
```

Repare que você faz a inclusão no banco e após a inclusão você faz o upload.

Faça dessa forma:

```
 public void salvar() {
        upload();
        this.noticia = cadastroNoticiaService.salvar(this.noticia);
        FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Noticia salva com sucesso! ");
        limpar();

}
```

O Upload deve ser feito primeiro para que o atributo `nomeArquivoSaida` não seja nulo na hora da inclusão.

Comment: nossa cara, muito obrigado, deu tudo certo, valeu mesmo.

Comment: Por nada cara, não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta pois assim poderá ajudar alguém com uma dúvida semelhante.